# sql server aggregate query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I need to achieve the query results in single row. below is the table structure

```
empno   Period  Actual  Budgeted
1   May     12.0     22.1
1   May     6.0     22.1
1   June    1.5     40.4
1   June    8.9     40.4
```

I need to get,
for May-> Actual sum to be 18, budgeted to be 22.1
and June -> Actual sum to be  10.4 , budgeted to be 40.4

Finally I should receive sum of all (actual), budgeted by distinct of period for empno =1

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please post (formatted) expected output and what you've tried so far. **Consumable** sample data would also be nice.

Comment: You need `GROUP BY` and then `PIVOT` but without a example of the result you want we cant help you any further

Comment: Ugh, May and June of what year? What happens when you have more than a year of data?

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Where's your query???  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select empno, period, sum(actual), max(budgeted) from MY_TABLE
where empno = 1
group by empno, period
```